# implementing a 802.15.4 math model based on a paper. How to verify it

Tags: modelling, markov-chains, queueing-theory

I am implementing a mathematic model for predicting the congestion of 802.15.4 network based on the paper:
[Performance analysis of IEEE 802.15.4 non-beacon mode with the unslotted CSMA/CA](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4489653)

Based on the system of nonlinear equations mentioned in that paper, I converted that formula into python code and solved it with "scipy". However, the prediction result is quite different from the one in the paper. I actually spent a few days to debug it, and even rewrited it in OCTAVE(another math program)(since I thought the reason might be on the nonlinear solver itself), but I failed in all manners.

Could someone help me check if my implementation has some flaws. Or it is proper to contact the authors of the paper?

HERE is my code:

```
# coding: utf-8

# In[58]:


from scipy.optimize import root
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')


# In[59]:


#parameters
BEmax=5
BEmin=3
MaxBF=4
UnitBFPeriod=0.32#320us
Tcca=0.25
Ttx=1.12
Tturn=0.192
Tack=0.352
Lamda=0.03
NumDev=0


# In[60]:


def W(j):
    global BEmax,BEmin,MaxBF,UnitBFPeriod,Tcca,Ttx,Tturn,Tack,Lamda,NumDev
    return min(2**(j+BEmin),2**BEmax)


# In[61]:


def meanGamma(ed):
    global BEmax,BEmin,MaxBF,UnitBFPeriod,Tcca,Ttx,Tturn,Tack,Lamda,NumDev
    rho=Lamda*(ed+Ttx+2*Tturn+Tack)
    return 1/(1-rho)


# In[62]:


#var[alpha,EDhol,Ploss]
def model_equ(var):
    global BEmax,BEmin,MaxBF,UnitBFPeriod,Tcca,Ttx,Tturn,Tack,Lamda,NumDev
    Ploss_zero=var[0]**(MaxBF+1)-var[2]
    first_verse=np.arange(MaxBF+1).astype('float')
    first_verse=var[0]**(first_verse)*(1-var[0])
    with np.nditer(first_verse, flags=['f_index'],op_flags=['readwrite']) as it:
        for x in it:
            temp=np.arange(it.index+1).astype('float')
            with np.nditer(temp,flags=['f_index'],op_flags=['readwrite']) as it2:
                for y in it2:
                    y[...]=(W(y)-1)/2*UnitBFPeriod+(x+1)*Tcca
            x[...]=x*np.sum(temp)
    sec_verse=np.arange(MaxBF+1).astype('float')
    with np.nditer(sec_verse, flags=['f_index'],op_flags=['readwrite']) as it:
        for x in it:
            x[...]=(W(x)-1)/2*UnitBFPeriod+(MaxBF+1)*Tcca
    EDhol_zero=np.sum(first_verse)+var[0]**(MaxBF+1)*np.sum(sec_verse)-var[1]
    Alpha_zero=((NumDev-1)*(1-var[2])*meanGamma(var[1])*(Tcca+Ttx+2*Tturn+Tack))/(1/Lamda+meanGamma(var[1])*var[1])-var[0]
    return np.array([Alpha_zero,EDhol_zero,Ploss_zero])


# In[63]:


def TP(var):
    global BEmax,BEmin,MaxBF,UnitBFPeriod,Tcca,Ttx,Tturn,Tack,Lamda,NumDev
    return (NumDev*(1-var[2])*meanGamma(var[1])*Ttx)/(1/Lamda+meanGamma(var[1])*(var[1]+Ttx+2*Tturn+Tack))


# In[64]:


def DELAY(var):
    global BEmax,BEmin,MaxBF,UnitBFPeriod,Tcca,Ttx,Tturn,Tack,Lamda,NumDev
    return (Lamda*2/(var[1]**2))/(2*(1-(Lamda*(var[1]+Ttx+2*Tturn+Tack))))+var[1]


# In[75]:


def plot_func(numd):
    global BEmax,BEmin,MaxBF,UnitBFPeriod,Tcca,Ttx,Tturn,Tack,Lamda,NumDev
    tp=[]
    delay=[]
    for x in range(numd):
        NumDev=x
        random.seed()
        sol = root(model_equ,([random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1), random.uniform(0, 1)]), method='hybr')
        tp.append(TP(sol.x))
        delay.append(DELAY(sol.x))
    nd=np.arange(numd)
    plt.plot(nd,tp,label='Lambda='+str(Lamda))
    #plt.show()


# In[77]:


Lamda=0.01
plot_func(25)
Lamda=0.02
plot_func(25)
Lamda=0.03
plot_func(25)
plt.legend()
plt.show()


# In[71]:





# In[ ]:
```

This code will plot a graph of throughput vs number of device, which is also showed on the paper. the graph is speciously similar with the one in the paper, but the throughput is slightly different.
[image: grapg result in my code]this is my graph.

Unfortunately I could not paste the graph in that paper due to copyright. I hope someone have access can help me tackle this problem.

Am I supposed to send a email to the author for help?

Comment: Coding questions and requests for help debugging your code are off-topic here.

Comment: Perhaps [scicomp.se] is a better site for this.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus yeah you are right. Thank you for noticing me